# Adding HTML text boxes to modify JS array items? Best practices and resources to study? Any recommendations welcome

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, append

Here's my current app: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MattNewtonian/r3509dqg/)

Given the following data I have here in arrays:

```
var mains = ["Chicken sammich", " Lasagna", " Plain Pizza", " Fried Beefcake", " Soylent Shake"];
var sides = ["Freedom fries", " Apple slices", " Tater tots", " Sad salad", " Hard-boiled egg"];
var desserts = ["Rice Pudding", " Gluten-free cookie", " Cheesecake Delux", " Sundae", " Graham Crackers"];
```

Is there an easy way for the user to modify these entries from the HTML? Or should I be using JS Objects for this instead?

Basically, the code works, and I want to learn how to add some HTML forms and buttons to replace these or add / remove their own. I know that sounds like a lot of work, so all I'm asking for are some *hints* here, because I want to learn!

I suppose I can create buttons that will .push and .pop the array elements. Something along the lines of....

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="Add a Main"> <script> tbody.appendChild(tr);</script>
```

```
button1.addEventListener(onClick)(runFunctionToAppendItemToArray ?)
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use framework like [Vue](https://vuejs.org/).
Or you can try to build this with vanila JS as you described. See my extremely ugly but working example.

```js
//your data
var data = ["a", "b"];

//search dom elements
var root = document.getElementById('list_editor');
var list = root.querySelector('lo');
var input = root.querySelector('input');
var btn = root.querySelector('button');
var arr_preview = root.querySelector('p');


// initialize
btn.addEventListener('click', new_item, false);
render_list();

function new_item(){
  data.push(input.value);
  render_list();
  input.value = '';
}

function render_list(){
  // wipe the list
  list.innerHTML = '';
  
  // I know For in should not be used with array
  for(var i in data){
  
    // create list item <li>
    var el = document.createElement('li');
    el.innerText = data[i];
    
    // create button to remove the item
    var rem_el = document.createElement('button');
    rem_el.innerText = 'remove';
    rem_el.addEventListener('click', rem(i), false);
    el.appendChild(rem_el);
    
    // insert to the DOM
    list.appendChild(el);
  }
  arr_preview.innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
}

// fn factory create scope, maybe not necesarry?
function rem(j){
  return function(){
    data.splice(j, 1);
    render_list();
   }
  
}
```

```html
<div id="list_editor">
<lo>
</lo>
<input type="text" placeholder="new item?"><button>insert</button>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent work and thanks! I don't think it's ugly at all, it works! Just needs some CSS love. Can I ask, why you suggest Vue for this sort of project? Thanks

Comment: @MattNewtonian, because Vue (same as other frameworks) streamlines the connection between your business logic and the UI.  You can focus more on the logic and less on fiddling with the code. Also, there is still some learning curve to get over, so maybe it's better to just learn more of JS and build the code on your own. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt to achieve your goals. I used jquery since you already have it in your code. I'm using a loop to populate the meals list in order to avoid freezing the UI while generating the random meals. I hope the code is clear enough for you to develop it further.

```js
const MEAL_COUNT = 31;

var LOOP; // the timeout loop

const wrapper = $('#meals');

var mains = ["Chicken sammich", "Lasagna", "Plain Pizza", "Fried Beefcake", "Soylent Shake"];
var sides = ["Freedom fries", "Apple slices", "Tater tots", "Sad salad", "Hard-boiled egg"];
var desserts = ["Rice Pudding", "Gluten-free cookie", "Cheesecake Delux", "Sundae", "Graham Crackers"];

var mealIdentifiers = [];

// here we will save the current selected dishes
var currentMains = [];
var currentSides = [];
var currentDesserts = [];

// this function automates the creation of the checkboxes 
var checkboxes = function(array) {
  var boxes = [];
  for (var item of array) {
    let box = $('<label><input type="checkbox" name="' + item + '" checked>' + item + '</label>');
    boxes.push(box);
  }
  return boxes;
};

$('#mains').append(checkboxes(mains));
$('#sides').append(checkboxes(sides));
$('#desserts').append(checkboxes(desserts));

// this is where we create new menu lists
var newMenu = function() {
  // first lets empty the old lists
  wrapper.empty();
  mealIdentifiers = [];
  
  // now lets save the current selected dishes
  currentMains = [];
  $('#mains input:checked').each(function(i, item) {
    currentMains.push(item.name);
  });

  currentSides = [];
  $('#sides input:checked').each(function(i, item) {
    currentSides.push(item.name);
  });

  currentDesserts = [];
  $('#desserts input:checked').each(function(i, item) {
    currentDesserts.push(item.name);
  });

  // now we start the loop (only runs once)
  if (!LOOP) LOOP = setInterval(addItem, 10);
};

// this will loop and add new meals just like in your code
var addItem = function () {
  if (mealIdentifiers.length < MEAL_COUNT) {

    // here I changed it to use the current items
    let mainId = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentMains.length);
    let sideId = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentSides.length);
    let dessertId = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentDesserts.length);

    // I added hashes between the integers to avoid false duplicates on longer lists
    // eg: before 11, 2, 3 would be the same as 1, 12, 3 ( 1123 == 1123 )
    // I changed it so 11#2#3 !== 1#12#3
    let mealId = [mainId, sideId, dessertId].join('#');

    // if there's no meal like that already
    if (!mealIdentifiers.includes(mealId)) {
      mealIdentifiers.push(mealId);

      let container = $('<div class="container">');

      container.append('<div class="date">' + (mealIdentifiers.length) + '</div>');

      // I added strings for when all checkboxes are empty
      container.append('<div class="main">' + (currentMains[mainId] || 'No main'));
      container.append('<div class="side">' + (currentSides[sideId] || 'No side'));
      container.append('<div class="dessert">' + (currentDesserts[dessertId] || 'No dessert'));

      wrapper.append(container);
    }
  }
};

// create the first menu
newMenu();

// create new menus on checkbox change
$('#customize').on('change', 'input', newMenu);
```

```css
.container {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  float: center;
}

#mealsDiv {
  float: center;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #7C9BC8;
}

.side {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #B878C8;
}

.dessert {
  color: #88C740;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#mains {
  color: #7C9BC8;
}

#sides {
  color: #B878C8;
}

#desserts {
  color: #88C740;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>This handy app helps you plan the perfect cafeteria meal without boring repetition! </h3>

<div id="customize">
  <h3>Current main dishes offered:</h3>
  <div id="mains"></div>
  <h3>Current side dishes offered:</h3>
  <div id="sides"></div>
  <h3>Current desserts offered:</h3>
  <div id="desserts"></div>
</div>

<div id="meals"></div>
```

Comment: Apologies for the late response - Excellent work! I think I'm going to try to learn jQuery (I forget how that script link got there) before trying to implement this. I love how you comment and structure your code, it makes it so easy to understand!